# SQL Server Management Studio 2008 - doesnot display varchar(max) full

Tags: sql-server-2008, max, varchar

I am sorry if this is a duplicate question. Please point me in correct direction. I have a table with a column  named MailBody with `varchar(max)` as datatype like below.

```
CREATE TABLE Mail
(
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [MailBody] [varchar](max) NULL
)
```

When I try to insert a very long string, length > 10,000 characters into `MailBody`, it is not storing full string. It is truncating and then storing the truncated string in `MailBody` column. Can anybody tell me how to store the full string but not truncated string into `MailBody` column.

**UPDATE**

As stated by marc_s below in one of his comments, it is storing the full MailBody string into MailBody column. I created a small C# unit test method to read MailBody column and saw that I am getting my full string without truncated. I didnot change any settings in my SSMS. Thanks marc_s

Comment: @Mihai: certainly ***NOT!*** - `ntext`, `text`, and `image` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)`, `varchar(max)`, and `varbinary(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Comment: When does that truncation happen? How are you inserting that data into the table? And how are you manipulating the data?

Comment: It looked like Mihai just got kicked across the field.

Comment: How are you loading.  I suspect you are getting truncated on the client side.

Comment: @ everyone.. i am trying to see whether I can solve the problem using varchar(max) datatype since the table is already in production and I donot want to change column datatype.

Comment: marc_s and Frisbee.. I am using a C# WCF service.. which will call a stored procedure.. WCF service will provide.. MailBody in string datatype. I saw here that string is not truncated. In my stored proc the input parameter is @MailBody varchar(max) = NULL OUTPUT. In stored procedure, it does nothing.. just gets MailBody in string from WCF service and puts into MailBody column in my table.

Comment: Can you use SQL Profiler and check if the entire mail body coming to DB without getting truncated cause VARCHAR(MAX) allows storage size upto 2GB and so this scenario would never arise.

Comment: How do you even conclude that the string is truncated? SQL Server Management Studio might not ***display*** the whole string - but it might just as well be stored! Try to use `LEN(MailBody)` to see what length your column's value really is...

Comment: Post the C# for the load and the SP.

Comment: @marc_s : How you make SQL SERVER Management Studio to display whole string.

Comment: @Ziggler: shown in my response

Comment: @marc_s . i used LEN(MailBody) and I got 303511.

Comment: @Ziggler: does that still seem truncated?? :-) Most likely *just* a SSMS display issue that fooled you ...

Comment: @marc_s : looking into it

Comment: I tested with C# unit test method. I am getting my full string back even though Server Management Studio not display the whole string .

Answer (score 0):

Using your table structure, I was easily able to insert a 120 KB+ `.txt` file into the table with this code:

```
INSERT INTO Mail(MailBody)
    SELECT BulkColumn
    FROM OPENROWSET (BULK 'c:\tmp\large.txt', SINGLE_CLOB) MyFile
```

This can be seen by checking the length of the `MailBody` column:

```
SELECT ID, LEN(MailBOdy) FROM Mail
```

Output:

[image]

`VARCHAR(MAX)` is **easily** able to handle large text - up to **2 billion** characters, actually - enough to hold way past 100 copies of the entire "War And Peace" by Leo Tolstoj. ....

**DO NOT** change your datatype - it's the ***right datatype*** to use! There must be something else going on that truncates your data ...

**Update:** you can set the amount of data that SSMS will show you under `Tools > Options`:

[image]

You can crank up the number of characters displayed - but be **aware:** the higher you go, the more data might need to be transferred to your computer to be displayed! Don't start complaining about lack of performance if you ask for 2 GB of data for each column! :-)

Comment: I didnot make any changes to Server Management Studio and created a C# unit test method and saw that I am getting my whole string back. I feel your this statement in above comments is correct.. "Server Management Studio might not display the whole string - but it might just as well be stored!"

Comment: @Ziggler: if this answer helped you solve your problem, then please [**accept this answer**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5234/153998). This will show your appreciation for the people who *spent their own time to help you*.

Comment: I also wanted to accept the answer but as I said your comment "Server Management Studio might not display the whole string - but it might just as well be stored!" guided me in right direction. I even tried what you said above SSMS -> Tools > Options but that didnot solve the problem. The actual answer/reason is SQL SERVER is storing the entire string but it's just not display it fully.

Comment: I also wanted to accept the answer but as I said your comment "Server Management Studio might not display the whole string - but it might just as well be stored!" guided me in right direction. I even tried what you said above SSMS -> Tools > Options but that didnot solve the problem. The actual answer/reason is SQL SERVER is storing the entire string but it's just not display it fully.